# Message box with image and text input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plugins

I need to be able to show an image along with two lines of input texts. 
I was wondering if anyone knows of a good minimalistic plugin that can do it.
It is for proxying a CAPTCHA like text. Not too big.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org), specifically the [Overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html).  It'll look something like this:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div><img src="" id="picture" /></div>
    <div><input type="text /><input type="text" /></div>
    <button class="close">Submit</button>
</div>
```

With basic overlay code:

```
$("#overlay").overlay({
    closeOnClick: false,
    closeOnEsc: false
});
```

You can then use the `onBeforeClose` event to perform any submission actions, validation, etc. (documentation [here](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html)).

If you need to change the image after the page is loaded, you can use the following:

```
$("#picture").attr("src", varWithSource);
```

If you need it, you can also use jQuery Tools's form tools for validation and structure it like a [form inside an overlay](http://jquerytools.org/demos/combine/html5-form/index.html).

Comment: Are you referring to a messageBox ? like javascript alert?